# Overriding rails 4 views inside custom gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rails-admin, rails-engines

I've been trying to override rails_admin views inside a custom theme that I've built (which so far only overrides css).

Is it at all possible to override rails_admin default views (like the dashboard for example), inside my theme?

PS: Simply putting the views inside an app/views folder inside the theme doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reached a possible solution, that, at first glance, seems to solve my issue completely.

After having a look at the rails plugin/engine mechanics, I noticed that, in order to include the plugins app folder and override other plugins (in this case rails_admin), I would need to require that folder on the gemspec file.

When using the rails_admin theme generator, this file is configured to only include the lib and vendor folders of the plugin.

In summary, i had to change the **.gemspec** file of my theme and include the app folder, like so:

```
s.files = Dir["{app,lib,vendor}/\*\*/\*", "MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.rdoc"]
```

I hope this helps anyone in a similar situation in the future.